How to invoke italic correction in ConTeXt LMTX?
Yesterday, I started diving into ConTeXt LMTX and I am already noticing a behavior I did not expect when it comes to italic correction. What is even more frustrating is that I am not able to find any information on this by searching the web, wiki and a few books I found on ConTeXt.
I cannot seem to produce italic correction like I could in plain TeX or even LaTeX. Can someone explain what is going on?
Here are the minimal working samples of code.
Plain TeX
Source code:
airport (regular font)

{\it air\/}port (italic correction applied)

{\it air}port (no italic correction applied)
\bye

Output:

ConTeXt
Source code:
\starttext
airport (regular font)

{\it air\/}port (italic correction applied)

{\it air}port (no italic correction applied)
\stoptext

Output:

Note
I installed ConTeXt LMTX following the instructions on:

The official website at https://www.pragma-ade.com/install.htm
Appendix A2 of A not so short introduction to ConTeXt

In case the version matters, here is the output of context --version:
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.06
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /home/vladimir/programs/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.08.13 15:03
mtx-context     | main context file: /home/vladimir/programs/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.08.13 15:03

Furthermore, context is just a symbolic link to luametatex as it can be seen from the following picture (these are the contents of the bin direcotry that was produced after running install.sh script).

If my operating system mattes, here is the output of uname -rs:
FreeBSD 14.1-RELEASE

it is perfectly normal for it to be a symbolic link. this is very usual for TeX programmes. (not just TeX, actually.) pdflatex, pdfetex, pdflatex-dev, pdfcsplain, pdfjadetex, pdfmex, mex, mllatex, mltex, latex, latex-dev and many more are all symbolic links to pdftex, for example.

@cfr I added that just in case. I wasn't implying that something was off. This is the first time I noticed such a thing becuase I normally install other TeX programs using the package manager. However, ConTeXt LMTX was not in the repository of my OS and I was under impression that texlive will not include ConTeXt.

well TeX Live certainly includes ConTeXt. I've not heard of a standard distro not include it. (I mean as opposed to a specialist linux distro or something which might include a minimal TL for some specific purpose.) however, it is often not part of the package called texlive as the installation is usually split up. probably not the issue here, but you can expect trouble if you try to combine programmes from your os distro and upstream because os distros are typically older and sometimes modified. you should stick to one or the other. (or install both is possible.)

@cfr Thanks. That is roughly the information I found. I do have texlive installed on my system, however, I did not have the context nor luametatex binaries installed. I didn't bother trying to figure out if other binaries installed with texlive would compile the LMTX version of ConTeXt, expecially once I figured that whatever (if anything) pertaining to ConTeXt that is in texlive is likely older than the current version. However, this is not the focus of my question.

The directory structure of a standard ConTeXt installation always looks pretty weird, so what you have there looks correct to me.

To enable italic correction in ConTeXt, you should use \adaptfontfeature[*][itlc=yes]. Unfortunately, this only works with the older LuaTeX engine, and not with the default LuaMetaTeX engine:
\startbuffer[demo]
    \startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
        airport

        {\it air\/}port

        {\it air}port
    \stopTEXpage
    % \starttext % Hack to make \typesetbuffer work properly
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[luatex]
    % engine=luatex
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[lmtx]
    % engine=luametatex
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[adapt]
    \adaptfontfeature[*][itlc=yes]
\stopbuffer

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    \setupTABLE[frame=off]
    \startTABLE
        \NC
        \NC \LuaTeX{}
        \NC \LuaMetaTeX{}
        \NC \NR

        \NC Original
        \NC \typesetbuffer[luatex,demo][frame=on]
        \NC \typesetbuffer[lmtx,demo][frame=on]
        \NC \NR

        \NC Adapted
        \NC \typesetbuffer[luatex,adapt,demo][frame=on]
        \NC \typesetbuffer[lmtx,adapt,demo][frame=on]
        \NC \NR
    \stopTABLE
\stopTEXpage



ConTeXt has a command called \setextrafontkerns that can add kerning between different fonts:

Extra font kerns
Fonts are processed independent of each other. Sometimes that is unfortunate for kerning, although in practice it won’t happen that often. We can enable an additional kerning mechanism to deal with these cases. The \setextrafontkerns command takes one argument. [...]



key
description




none
only extra kerns within fonts


min
minimal kerns within and across fonts


max
maximum kerns within and across fonts


mixed
averaged kerns within and across fonts



This mechanism obeys grouping so you have complete control over where and when it gets applied.
(source)

Unfortunately, the pair rp is unkerned in Latin Modern, so this also doesn't help us here:
\setupTABLE[c][1][style=tt]
\startbuffer[table]
    \startTABLE[frame=off]
        \NC none
        \NC \showfontkerns\setextrafontkerns[none]\inlinebuffer
        \NC \NR

        \NC min
        \NC \showfontkerns\setextrafontkerns[min]\inlinebuffer
        \NC \NR

        \NC max
        \NC \showfontkerns\setextrafontkerns[max]\inlinebuffer
        \NC \NR

        \NC mixed
        \NC \showfontkerns\setextrafontkerns[mixed]\inlinebuffer
        \NC \NR
    \stopTABLE
\stopbuffer

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    \dontleavehmode
    \startbuffer
        oc \italic{o}c \italic{oc}
    \stopbuffer%
    \framed{\getbuffer[table]}%
    ~
    \startbuffer
        rp \italic{r}p \italic{rp}
    \stopbuffer%
    \framed{\getbuffer[table]}
\stopTEXpage



Since none of the theoretically-correct solutions actually work, we'll have to use a hacky solution. It does seem to work properly, but I wouldn't really recommend using it since it involves modifying internal ConTeXt macros:
\skipfontcharacteristicsfalse

\unprotect
\appendtoks%
    \ifx\fontalternative\s!it%
        \ifvmode%
            \dontleavehmode%
        \fi%
        \shapecorrection[both]%
    \fi%
\to\everyfontswitch%
\protect

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    airport

    {\it air\/}port

    {\it air}port
\stopTEXpage


For a proper solution, report this issue to the ConTeXt mailing list ntg-context@ntg.nl and one of the developers will likely release a fix for it.

Thank you for the detailed response. Your hacky solution is definitely something I would want to avoid so I will report this this as an issue.
